# Hide attribute label for variable products in Woocommerce Single product page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, label, dropdown

I am trying to hide the attribute label in woocommerce single product pages (the word "color" and "size" in attached image)…

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: What exactly is blocking you with that? Always try to describe what you did and what kind of error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to add in the `styles.css` file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*:

```css
.single-product table.variations td.label > label {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Tested and works.

> As you are **using a plugin that display custom swatches**, you will need to replace some selectors to make it work for you, **until you will give a live link to your website**.
>
> Without **a live link to your website**, is not possible to guess the html structure.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is working great. I just removed > label to make it work. The final CSS which I used, .single-product table.variations td.label {
    display: none !important;
}.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I hide the Attribute label

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'remove_attribute_label');
function remove_attribute_label() {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: this works to remove the label but you still need css to hide the table cell that the label was in otherwise you have extra space to the left of your variation drop-down